# Append Rows to CSV File (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've borrowed the below code from TommyGun on MrExcel, but I got the following difficulties:

1. At the end of the generated file, it repeats the delimiters in the rows below, even though there is no data in between them;
2. The File name would have to be dynamically generated, according to the month we're in, but 'Const CSVFile As String' doesn't accept Format(date, "mmm-yy") as a string element, for example.

```
Sub Append2CSV()
Dim tmpCSV As String 'string to hold the CSV info
Dim f As Integer

Const CSVFile As String = "C:\VBA Code\test.csv" 'replace with your filename

f = FreeFile

Open CSVFile For Append As #f
tmpCSV = Range2CSV(Range("A2:H3"))
Print #f, tmpCSV
Close #f
End Sub

Function Range2CSV(list) As String
Dim tmp As String
Dim cr As Long
Dim r As Range

If TypeName(list) = "Range" Then
cr = 1

For Each r In list.Cells
    If r.Row = cr Then
        If tmp = vbNullString Then
            tmp = r.Value
        Else
            tmp = tmp & "," & r.Value
        End If
    Else
        cr = cr + 1
        If tmp = vbNullString Then
            tmp = r.Value
        Else
            tmp = tmp & Chr(10) & r.Value
        End If
    End If
Next
End If

Range2CSV = tmp
End Function
```

How about considering the following:
If the files doesn't exist, then create it with the header (row 1). If it does, then append (range"A2:S" & lastorw)

Comment: You can't define a constant with a dynamic expression, so try `Dim CsvFile As String` and then assign `CsvFile = Format(Now, "mmm-yy")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate the first problem (trailing line(s) of delimiters in the output CSV). In order to make your filename dynamic, it should either be given as a `Dim` (instead of a constant expression `Const`), or you should use string `Replace` against a constant expression. Using a `Dim` variable as below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Append2CSV()
Dim tmpCSV As String 'string to hold the CSV info
Dim f As Integer

Dim CSVFile As String
CSVFile = "C:\VBA Code\" & Format(Date, "MMM-YY") & ".csv"

f = FreeFile

Open CSVFile For Append As #f
tmpCSV = Range2CSV(Range("A2:H3"))
Print #f, tmpCSV
Close #f
End Sub
```

Input data:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi! The reason may then be because there is formula in the cells originating the data....?

Comment: Yes that could be the case, if the formula results in "empty" string value.

Comment: Hi there!
I've added an additional situation to see if you guys can help me...

Comment: If you have an "additional situation", you should ask a new/separate question. Does this answer solve the problem? If not, please clarify within scope of the question as it was originally asked. You may be expected to provide some [mcve] including example input & output, so that everyone can understand what you are working with.

Comment: Hi! I do understand the concept, but the line is really tender here. The additional situation is directly related to the above question and that's why I've edited the question, adding it to the bottom. Could you confirm it has to be in a separate question? Again, I appreciate all the help/clarifications here! Cheers.

Comment: No, it's not directly related. It's only related to your particular use case. Further, there are easily dozens of questions on here which can assist you in determine if the file not exist. You could try open Read mode and trap error, you could use FileSystemObject method, or you could [use Dir function](https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/vba-dir-function-to-check-if-file-exists/). Can you try to implement that, along with other logic?